# Oracle connection string without a DSN

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I currently connect to an Oracle database in C#. NET2.0 using the following database connection string:

```
 Dsn=myDSNs;uid=me;pwd=mypassword
```

What I'd really like to do is connect using a connection string that doesn't need a DSN (to save me configuring ~100 machines).

I've tried many variations of the following:

```
 Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myService))); uid=me; pwd=mypassword;
```

But keep getting the following exception;

```
ExceptionType: OdbcException
Message: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I'm fairly confident the parameters (service name, port, host) are correct as they are used in another client that works so I'm starting to wander if I'm barking up the wrong tree? Any enlightenment would be great.

Comment: We use the same but with id instead of uid and password instead of pwd and it works

Answer (score 0):

just try with following string

```
 <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=DataBaseName;PASSWORD=tiger;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=me;Password=mypassword" />
```